# Other than はじめまして, what can we say in our introduction?

Tags: culture, phrase-requests, greetings

Other than はじめまして, what else can we say at the beginning of our introduction when meeting someone for the first time? Also, what else do we need to say when introducing ourselves other than our name that will be considered polite by the Japanese people? Can someone give me an example in Japanese of a good way of introducing ourselves for the first time?

Comment: In fiction in super formal situations characters sometimes say お初｛はつ｝にお会｛あ｝いします or お初｛はつ｝にお目｛め｝にかかります, but I don't know if that's used much in real life.

Answer (score 6):

はじめまして is a good start. This is how you open the conversation. It's roughly equivalent to "How do you do?" (which people don't really say anymore). You're indicating that it's your first meeting, so you are extending a courteous greeting.

Usually, the next step is to say your name:
(In my case) ロバートと申します (very polite)
ロバートと言います/です (a little more casual).
Sometimes you can give details about yourself before your name to give the other person a better idea of who you are.
オーストラリアから来たロバートです. (I'm Robert; I come from Australia). Alternatively, you could say whose friend you are, what you're studying or at what level, or what section of the company you work in.

At this point, your partner will introduce themselves.

Now you indicate you hope you can get along in future (roughly the same as "nice to meet you" in English), and add a bow.

> (どうぞ)よろしくお願いします.

To be more polite (for instance in business situations) you can say いたします instead of します.

Your partner will return this greeting.

Depending on the situation, you can have more small talk to clarify who the other person is or identify yourself more clearly.

There can be more casual ways of doing this. You could say よろしく instead of よろしくお願いします, for instance.

If you're non-Japanese, typically the other person wants to know where you are from, how and for long you have studied Japanese, when you came to Japan, what you're doing in Japan and so on. There will usually be a customary compliment on your Japanese level, which you are supposed to downplay with まだまだです (I'm not quite good at it yet) or some equivalent.

If you make a mistake in your introduction, Japanese people are generally forgiving, in my experience.

(That is usually how it goes from my 1.5 years of living in Japan.)

Answer (score -1):

Though the answer might depend on the purpose you came to Japan, after making the simple self-introduction such as Robert showed, I recommend you to say not by yourself but by the interpreter what you noticed at the entrance, what you were interested in on the street, what made you in trouble on the way to here, the place where you want to visit tonight, etc. except what you knew in preconceptions before coming to Japan. The newer is the better, and the more unpredictable is the better.

Probably there will be various reactions for your additional self-introduction like simple answers, advice, proposals, invitations, etc. from the Japanese who heard it.

I thereby think you may achieve the purpose that you came to Japan for more smoothly, earlier and more efficiently, thanks to the additional self-introduction.

Comment: Er... what exactly does this have to do with self-introductions?

Comment: @Blavius I assume that you do not understand Japanese and you need an interpreter to achieve the purpose that you've come to Japan.
Therefore I think you are better to entrust the interpreter even including the complicated self-introduction of yours except the first very simple one like はじめまして わたしは ＊＊＊＊ ともうします。
After the self-introduction of yours through the interpreter or after the wind-up meeting you have the chance to express what was suggested in my answer.

Comment: Are you serious? Please tell me you're not serious.

Comment: @Blavius It's not a Joke. I'm always sincere in answering the question at this site. I would recommend the questioner to learn the basic form of greetings not in this site but in the book where the correctness of contents is fully checked.
Now I intend to give him/her a true knack to have him/her effectively achieve the purpose of visiting Japan. It's the knack to remove the barriers between him/her and the partners in Japan; not the skill of speaking Japanese.

Comment: I think mackygoo's point is that getting along with Japanese when you're staying in Japan is very important in greetings and self-introductions. So being able to speak perfect Japanese is not the be all and end all of learning Japanese. However, I think Blavius is trying to say it's unfair if a Japanese learner (which many people visiting this site are) is told to use an interpreter when speaking Japanese. It kind of defeats the purpose of learning Japanese and is quite discouraging. You would hope a Japanese learner might eventually learn how to speak without an interpreter.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your deep consideration for the sincere learners of Japanese language.
I presumed in answering the question that the person who wanted the way of self-introduction is a person who is temporarily visiting Japan on business.
If not I would answer in the other way. I have no intention to take the Japanese learners lightly. I'm willing to answer the questions in this site sincerely. I hope you to visit the site written below. Thank you!
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47230/how-do-japanese-understand-non-standard-words-without-looking-at-kanji/47239#47239

Comment: I've read some of your other comments, so I'm not doubting your sincerity. Your knowledge of Japanese and your willingness to help are appreciated, I'm sure :-)

Comment: I don't think this gives an *answer* to the question as worded, but I think it has good pedagogical value insofar as it highlights a cultural difference in expectations. Many Westerns not acculturated to Japan expect that they should try to use as much Japanese as possible during a visit regardless of their level or purpose. Conversely, many Japanese do not expect Westerners to use any Japanese ...

Comment: 質問を読んだ時、質問者は日本語の勉強されていないかどうかことは全くわからないです。それはありうるが、授業か独学で「はじめまして」の表現を習って、バリエーションを勉強するため、聞いている可能性も否定できない。

Comment: You have a point there (in both comments). It's hard to think what else you would use other than はじめまして except in casual situations where you have more leeway. Japanese seems more formulaic on first meetings than English, where you don't necessarily have to say, 'Nice to meet you. My name is ...' You're right about the cultural differences. But if you use only English and stray too far from the Japanese greeting pattern, there are situations where this could cause problems. I had students who were confused if I omitted this formula even when I was teaching an English class in English.

Comment: @vimaior あなたを含めて他の人の私の回答に対するコメント読んで、私の回答が、回答の前提条件を明確にしていなかったために誤解を生じたことを反省しています。私は商用で日本に来たビジネスマンが自己紹介する場面を想定して回答しました。 さらに、そのビジネスマンは日本語が上手でないと判断しました。その場合大切なのは上手な自己紹介ではなく、ビジネスを成功さすための効果的な行動がもっと大切だと判断しました。ビジネスを成功させる秘訣は、ビジネスパートナーとの間に生じるいろいろな障壁を早く取り去ることです。そのために、形式的な自己紹介より、パートナーとの親密な関係構築が大切だと思いました。そのための方法として日本人のパートナーが興味をいだく話題を提供する、あるいは、仕事を離れたときに会話が継続できる話題の提供が大切だと思いました。私の回答が日本語を熱心に勉強している学習者に失礼になった可能性があることに関しては深く反省しています。